# Lists alphabetical ordered by javascript with letter headings

Tags: javascript, list, sql-order-by, alphabetical

I have a list like this:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li><a href="/">Adam</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Alex</a></li>
    ...
    <li><a href="/">Zara</a></li>            
</ul>
```

And it is already alphabetical ordered by this JavaScript:

```
var mylist = $('#list');
var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
})
$.each(listitems, function(idx, itm) { mylist.append(itm); });
```

Now I need to set the list like this:

```
<ul id="list">
    <li id="a"><a name="a" class="title">A</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Adam</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Alex</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="b"><a name="b" class="title">B</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Barry</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">Becky</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <li id="z"><a name="z" class="title">z</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">zavv</a></li>
            <li><a href="/">zora</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

To use the list in this [Apple Style Slider](http://devgrow.com/slidernav/).

Do you know how can I do it with JavaScript?

Answer (score 6):

It would be easiest (I guess) to collect all `li` elements in an object first (categorized bei their content's initial letter) and then sort those lists separately. Since code says more than a thousand words, here's how I would do that:

```
var list = { letters: [] };    //object to collect the li elements and a list of initial letters
$("#list").children("li").each(function(){
    var itmLetter = $(this).text().substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
    if (!(itmLetter in list)) {
        list[itmLetter] = [];
        list.letters.push(itmLetter);
    }
    list[itmLetter].push($(this));    //add li element to the letter's array in the list object
});

list.letters.sort();    //sort all available letters to iterate over them
$.each(list.letters, function(i, letter){
    list[letter].sort(function(a, b) {
        return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());    //sort li elements of one letter
    });
    var ul = $("<ul/>");    //create new dom element and add li elements
    $.each(list[letter], function(idx, itm){
        ul.append(itm);
    });
    $("#list").append($("<li/>").append($("<a/>").attr("name", letter.toLowerCase()).addClass("title").html(letter)).append(ul));    //add the list to a new li and to #list ul
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KnC6M/

Comment: it works like a charm!!! thank you so much!!! you saved me ;) thumbs up for Aletheios!!! just one question: why do you use the line $("#list").empty(); ?

Comment: Glad it works for you. Perhaps you could accept my answer... (the small checkmark above) ;) `$("#list").empty()` removes the original `li` elements from the `<ul id="list">` in order to add the newly generated items.

Comment: good, as i thought. that line cause a bug with my script..the links inside the list elements doesn't work (it is a link to change location in a custom google map without reloading page). if i delete that line, all works fine. do you think it could create some problems without that line?

Comment: Just guessing, but that could have to do something with event handlers... But I just noticed that the script also works fine without that line (don't ask me why) - I corrected it above.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Aletheios, I updated your solution to make it more efficient solution with the use of `css` without removing list by `$("#list").empty();`

**Assuming your list is already sorted.**

```
var letters = [];

$("#list").children("li").each(function(i){
    var itmLetter = $(this).text().trim().substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
    if (letters.indexOf(itmLetter)<0) {
        console.log(`${itmLetter} is not in ${letters} and index is ${i}`);
        $(`#list li:nth-child(${i+1})`).addClass("AddContent").attr('data-content',itmLetter);
        letters.push(itmLetter);
    } else {
        console.log(`${itmLetter} is in ${letters}`);
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
#list{
  margin-left: 15px;
}

li.AddContent:before {
   content: attr(data-content);
   margin-left: -15px;
   display: block;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <ul id="list">
      <li><a href="/">    Zara</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">    Adam</a></li>
      <li><a href="/">   Alex</a></li>            
      <li><a href="/">   Toby</a></li>
  </ul>
```

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KnC6M/105/

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for something similar, I wanted to sort an array in alphabetically grouped manner. Here is my code which is little modified version of @Aletheios code. Hope it helps.

```
var list = { letters: [] };
var words = {let: ['abc', 'aabbgg', 'cda', 'hello', 'bca']};

$.each(words.let, function(){                
    var itLetter = this.substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
    if(!(itLetter in list)){
        list[itLetter] = [];                    
        list.letters.push(itLetter);
    }
    list[itLetter].push($(this));
});

list.letters.sort();
$.each(list.letters, function(i, letter){

    var ul = $("<ul/>");
    var li = $('<li/>');
    $.each(list[letter], function(idx, itm){
        ul.append('<li>'+ itm[0] +'</li>');
        console.log(itm);

    });
    $("body").append($("<li/>").append($("<a/>").attr("name", letter.toLowerCase()).addClass("title").html(letter)).append(ul));
});
```

Here is the fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/checkomkar/x8taqcnk/